# data issue when reading csv on sharepoint folder with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, sharepoint

I am trying to use pandas to read a csv file stored on the sharepoint folder. In one of columns (Application Number) of that csv, some cells have string like '602013000000'. They are shown as scientific notation value when opening the csv file with Excel, such as 6.02E+11.

When I use pandas to read this file, I found above value is retrieved as 6.02E+11, instead of 602013000000. Below is the script I used:

```
response = File.open_binary(ctx, "/".join([folder_relative_url,newest]))
df = pd.read_csv(io.BytesIO(response.content),dtype={'Application Number':str})
```

Even I forced the data type to be changed to str type, the outcome still shows scientific notation format. I also tried to replace BytesIO with StringIO but no luck.

```
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(str(response.text),dtype={'Application Number':str}))
```

Is there any way I can retrieve the full string, instead of its scientific notation? Any suggestion would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly it is not really a Python problem but more an Excel problem on how it shows to you when you open the file in Excel, correct?

If so, you could try to change the format of Excel itself to show numbers not in scientific notation.